# Saving image list in a dir

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
X_image_train = []
for fname in os.listdir(images_dir):
    fpath = os.path.join(images_dir, fname)
    im = Image.open(fpath)
    im_resized = im.resize(dim)
    X_image_train.append(im_resized)
```

I want to save the above X_image_train list as dir in my laptop. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Image` objects from the `PIL` package, simply use `im.save('folder/path', 'JPEG')` in your foor loop